# How do I calculate the accuracy for graph mining in terms of (top 1%)?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, accuracy, graphs, confusion-matrix

I have 3600 samples in my dataset. I split the dataset into the `train (2700)` and `test (900)`.

My problem is related to `new link prediction`. I am using the `Common Neighbor (CN)` method. Using CN, we can predict new links based on the `score`. The score comes from the CN formula. CN gives a score for every possible edge/path/link. A higher score means a higher possibility to be a new link.

Now, I applied my train dataset to the CN methods. From CN, I have received 4200 new links with a score. From this 4200, I took only the `top 1%` (based on the score given by CN). So, the `top 1% is 42`.

Now, I tried to match the 42 with my test dataset. Means, actually, how many edges/links/path I can `recover` which were `missing` in the training dataset.

Among these 42 (CN output), `38 samples are perfectly matched` with the test dataset (means same edge/link/path of the train and test). But, I did not give or these 38 edges/link/paths were missing in the training dataset.

```
True Positive: 38
False Positive: 42-38 = 04
False Negative: 900-38 = 862
True Negative: 900 - (38 + 04 + 862) = -04
```

From this, I am trying to calculate `Precision, Recall, Accuracy`. But, what is happening, I am getting very little `Accuracy and Recall`.

Can you give me an idea to improve the `Accuracy` and `Recall`?

Comment: do you have a (binary) classification problem? it does not seem so, so TP, FP, TN, FN do not seem relevant

Comment: Yes, this is a binary classification problem but not in the sense of machine learning. I am using graph mining. For example, the 900 test data set contains all positive samples.

Comment: The FN is (900-38). But is it same for the top 1% also? Because, I am taking only top 1%. How can I calculate TN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mining problem which is basically a search problem. In search problem you have TP, FP, FN but not TN (you have it but it is trivial, imagine search in google. Basically bilions of webpages are TN in every search. right?)

I also assume that you are not interested in ranking results as you did not mention it in the question.

In this case you can easily go with Precision and recall:

- TP: Graphs which are right and you could find.
- FP: Graphs which are not right but your model found.
- FN: Graphs which are right but your model did not find.

Then you simply calculate:

Precision: $$\frac{TP}{TP+FP}$$
Recall: $$\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$$

And as a combined score, you may calculate F1:
$$\frac{2TP}{2TP+FP+FN}$$

### About Accuracy

When the volume of search space is huge, as I said above, accuray is not meaning much. According to the formulation:

$$ACC=\frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}$$

when $TN$ is very large then the whole fraction approaches zero and does not inform much.

But if your search space is relatively small, you can calculate accuracy with the formulation above. However it was just a theoretical justification and still your best metrics are precision and recall and their related metrics.

### Update For Your Specific Question

Your set of top 1% results may have different sizes due to different size of your model output (If it is always 4200 please write in the comments but in "mining" questions usually the size of output is variant).

In your case TP and FP are pretty straight-forward and meaningful. About FN, if your test set is also ranked, then you can evaluate your results according to top 1% of your ground-truth which includes 90 samples and go on as you already did, or you can fix the size of ground-truth set equal to your 1% (i.e. take 42 top test results) and again calculate same scores. The first one is more stable and significant for comparing different models.

A more precise metric which is related to the ranked results is called [NDCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain).

If the test set is not ranked then go this way:

- $|correctly\_found\_graphs|$: Number of graphs that you correctly found.
- $|wrongly\_found\_graphs|$: Number of graphs you found but they are not in ground-truth
- $|all\_found\_graphs|$: here 42
- $|all\_correct\_graphs|$: here 900

Then calculate [Precision@k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)) (here **precision@42**) metric which calculates the precision only on the top k results of a search output:

$Precision@42 = \frac{|correctly\_found\_graphs|}{|all\_found\_graphs|}=\frac{38}{42}$

This is a well-established information retrieval metric.

$Recall = \frac{|correctly\_found\_graphs|}{|all\_correct\_graphs|}=\frac{38}{900}$

***How can I improve the recall?***

As long as size of your top 1% results is less than ground-truth, your recall is limited to an upper-bound i.e. even if all 42 all relevant, still your recall is 42/900. Knowing this fact you can use recall but I do not see the point. Recall makes more sense if you take all 4200 outputs into account.
Your calculation of True Negative in the comments is also wrong. TN in your case is the number of all graphs that your model should not have returned and it didn't i.e. 900-42

***Moreover, all samples are positive in my test dataset. Not single sample is negatives***

See the problem from an Information Retrieval point of view. In this approach, any graph which is not in 900 set is a negative sample.

You can comment in case it is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, I am interested in the ranking result. As I said in the question that (top 1%) which is based on the score given by my model. In my cases, what I am getting, True Positive: 38
False Positive: 42-38 = 04
False Negative: 900-38 = 862
True Negative: 900 - (38 + 04 + 862) = -04. So, if I apply the formula you gave, I am getting Precision is good but Recall is very bad. Could you tell me, my calculation is right or wrong? How can I improve the Recall? Moreover, do I have to subtract 38 ( true positive for top 1%) from whole test dataset (900)?

Comment: Moreover, all samples are positive in my test dataset. Not single sample is negatives. This is one problem also.

Comment: I updated the answer. Plz comment if still unclear

Comment: I can't express my gratitude to you. Yes, the output is different (not fixed to 42). Your answer clears a lot of confusion. However, for `TN` do you mean (`all graphs mean is training + testing dataset`)? My test dataset is not ranked. I am scared the if I take the top 1%  (42) from ground truth then I will get less number `TP`. Moreover, what do you think about my `Precision` and `Recall`? I am trying to do something `link prediction` and my problem is related to `Drug-Drug Interactions`.

Comment: Welcome my friend! Well now the situation is different. First of all, how is the output of a link-prediction problem, a graph? Usually the output in link prediction is "if a specific link exists or not" ... Please give more precise info on your input and output and I will give the answer to your project ;)

Comment: Perfect. You got it. Say, I have 100 samples in a dataset. Then I split this into 70 (training) and 30 (testing). I applied a method (`shortest path or Common Neighbor etc.`). Now, I am getting 1000 output (please, be noted the number of output is different for different methods). Now, I too top 1% (which is 10) from the output. Then I marrying to match `how many edges/link` I can match with the test dataset (3). From this, I am trying to calculate `Precision, Recall, Accuracy`. But, what is happening, I am getting very little `Accuracy and Recall`. Please, let me know if you have any question

Comment: Oops, sorry. I wore test dataset (3). It must be 30.

Comment: Good. There is this confusion still. Your input is a set of graphs and your output is ... what?  .... In Common Neighbor, the input is a single node and output is a set of nodes. In shortest path, you have a search problem means that the input is a graph and the output is a path. We can not formulate a general framework that works for all these settings.I still think if you precisely write your question down it will be easier. I feel some info is missing or at least misleading here

Comment: Oops sorry for the confusion. Yes, Common Neighbor (CN) gives us a set of nodes. But using CN we can predict a new link/path from a graph. Because, CN gave us a score for every possible link/path from every node. A high score means a high possibility. In terms of Shortest Path (SP), yes we are getting a path as output. I am applying different methods (shortest path is 1 model and CN is another model). We can say our output is also different (1 for SP, and 1 for CN). Ultimately, we are getting a list of prospective links/paths from SP, and CN. Now, I am taking top 1% and trying to match test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122412/discussion-between-0knowledge-and-kasra-manshaei).

Comment: So finally you will have a set of predicted links (edges) and their score as the output. And you have also a set of links from your test set. Now we are working with edges. Right. I update the answer

Comment: I have a question, you said 'About FN, I can take top 1% (if ranked)'. Now, if I take the top 1% from the test dataset is 90. So, my FN = 90 - 38 = 52. Is this a well-established procedure to take the top 1% to calculate FN?